# How to merge two arrays of objects based on a object attribute OrderNo? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have 2 arrays of objects

```
var arrayObj1 = [
  {
   "Plant": "Boston",
   "OrderNo": "406643",
   "Qty1": "56.1650",
   "OrderDate": null,
   "Status": null
  }
 ];

var arrayObj2 = [
  {
    "Plant": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "406643",
    "Qty2": "22.07",
     "OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
     "Status": null
   },
   {
     "Plant": "Boston",
      "OrderNo": "526209",
      "Qty2": "21.84",
      "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
       "Status": null
     },
     {
       "Plant": "Boston",
        "OrderNo": "526209",
        "Qty2": "65.46",
        "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
        "Status": null
      }
    ];
```

My comparing parameter is OrderNo, if order number is same then that object has both finite Qty1 and Qty2.

Suppose in first array of object Qty1 exists (greater than 0) but for corresponding OrderNo no Qty2 exists in the 2nd array of object then Qty2 should be 0 in the newly created 3rd  array of object. SImilarly for a orderNo, if Qty2 exists (greater than 0) in 2nd  array of object but for corresponding OrderNo no Qty1 exists in 1st  array of object then Qty2 should be 0  in the newly created 3rd  array of object. Also we have to consider that any one of the two array of objects can completely blank array.

I want to create a new array of object like this

```
var arrayObj3 = [
  {
    "Plant": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "406643",
    "Qty1": "56.1650",// both Qty1 and Qty2 more than since both exists
    "Qty2": "22.07",// for the OrderNo 406643
     "OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
     "Status": null
   },
   {
     "Plant": "Boston",
      "OrderNo": "526209",
     "Qty1": "0",// Qty1 is 0 as it does not exist for OrderNo 526209
      "Qty2": "21.84",
      "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
       "Status": null
     },
     {
       "Plant": "Boston",
        "OrderNo": "526209",
        "Qty1": "0",// Qty1 is 0 as it does not exist for OrderNo 526209
        "Qty2": "65.46",
        "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
        "Status": null
      }
    ];
```

How can I easily achieve my desired array of object ie. arrayObj3. Can someone provide me a solution in Vanilla JS (without JQuery and Lodash)?

Some people are misunderstanding the logic. In first array of object Qty1 exists (greater than 0) but for corresponding OrderNo no Qty2 exists in the 2nd array of object then Qty2 should be 0 in the newly created 3rd  array of object. SImilarly for a orderNo, if Qty2 exists (greater than 0) in 2nd  array of object but for corresponding OrderNo no Qty1 exists in 1st  array of object then Qty2 should be 0  in the newly created 3rd  array of object. Also we have to consider that any one of the two array of objects can completely blank array.

Comment: At any one time, how many objects can there be at `arrayObj1`? Can there be more than 1?

Comment: @wentjun Any number - 1, 2 , 3, 4 etc, even arrayObj1/arrayObj2 can be a blank array. Both array are coming as responses of 2 services/APIs

Comment: Your example shows two items in arrayObj2 with the same OrderNo, you haven't described clearly how you want this to be handled. If you allow duplicate OrderNo in each of the original 2 arrays, how should they be matched up? Your description describes the case for single matches, but your example is more complex

Comment: You also don't say how Plant, OrderDate and Status should be merged. Do you assume that they are always the same?

Comment: @zakum1 Plant will always be same, OrderDate and Status are not very relevant

Comment: zakum If two objects with same order number are present, then both will be inserted in new object

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map:

```js
// create a map
var setObj = {};

// add the items from the first array
arrayObj1.forEach((item) => { setObj[item.OrderNo] = item; });

// add (or merge) the items from the second array
arrayObj2.forEach((item) => { 
    if (setObj[item.OrderNo]) {
        setObj[item.OrderNo].Qty2 = item.Qty2;
    } else {
        setObj[item.OrderNo] = item;
    }
});

// extract the resulting array from the set
var arrayObj3 = Object.values(setObj);
```

Rather than use a simple JS object `{}` as the map on the first line, you can also use
the JS `Map`:

```
var setObj = new Map();
```

This has better performance if you have a lot of data. You need to use `get()` and `set()` with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

There are other algorithms which are faster, but I think that for your use case, the above code is simple and easy to understand.

My code does not replicate your expected result, because you have duplicate keys and it is not clear what you intend for duplicates, but you should be able to adapt what I have done to accomodate this.

Comment: Can you kindly create a fiddle/JSFiddle?

Comment: Have you considered the cases that any one or both arrayObj1 and arrayObj2 can be blank array

Comment: yes, it will work for empty arrays. i think it should be easy to copy it into a fiddle to try out these cases. the code works with your variable names.

Comment: Misses the 3rd object completely

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Basically `qty1` for any order should be from first array and `qty2` from the second array. By that logic, the solution is:

```js
function mergeObjects (arr1, arr2, localKey, remoteKey) {
  
  return arr1.map(item => {
    var retObj = {...item};
    var ind = arr2.findIndex(x => item.OrderNo === x.OrderNo);
    var order = arr2[ind];
    if (order && parseFloat(retObj[localKey]) > 0 && order[remoteKey]) {
      arr2.splice(ind, 1);
      retObj[remoteKey] = order[remoteKey];
    }
    retObj[remoteKey] = retObj[remoteKey] || 0;
    return retObj;
  })
}

function createArray (arr1, arr2) {
  return [
    ...mergeObjects(arr1, arr2, 'Qty1', 'Qty2'),
    ...mergeObjects(arr2, arr1, 'Qty2', 'Qty1'),
  ]
}

var arrayObj1 = [
  {
    "Plant": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "406643",
    "Qty1": "56.1650",
    "OrderDate": null,
    "Status": null
  }
];

var arrayObj2 = [
  {
    "Plant": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "406643",
    "Qty2": "22.07",
    "OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
    "Status": null
  },
  {
    "Plant": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "526209",
    "Qty2": "21.84",
    "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
    "Status": null
  },
  {
    "Plant": "Boston",
    "OrderNo": "526209",
    "Qty2": "65.46",
    "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
    "Status": null
  }
];
console.log(createArray(arrayObj1, arrayObj2))
```

Comment: Can you kindly create a fiddle/JSFiddle?

Comment: The entire code is right there, just copy and paste it.

Comment: Have you considered the cases that any one or both arrayObj1 and arrayObj2 can be blank array

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: arrayObj2 is not defined", when 2nd array is blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple solution, it uses Object.assign to create a copy from one object to another object. Here temp obj is used for a place holder, thus not affecting the original objects.

```
//Merged List
var mergedList = new Array();
//For each item in array2
arrayObj2.forEach(function(item){
//filter by orderNo with array1
    arrayObj1.filter(function(item2){
        if(item2.OrderNo===item.OrderNo){
            let temp ={};
            Object.assign(temp,item,item2);
            mergedList.push(temp);
        }else{
            if(!item.hasOwnProperty('Qty1')){
                let temp ={};
                Object.assign(temp,item);
                temp["Qty1"] = "";
                mergedList.push(temp);
            }
           if(!item.hasOwnProperty('Qty2')){
                let temp ={};
                Object.assign(temp,item);
                temp["Qty2"] = "";
                mergedList.push(temp);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ejqn8c6b/1/

Comment: Can you please provide me a Fiddle ?

Comment: JS fiddle added , please check the result on log